# Django isnull query with mysql datefield not working

Tags: mysql, django, datefield

I have model class similar to this:

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    manager_id = models.ForeignKey(db_index=True,max_length=20)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The records are being stored in **mysql db**.

When i use the query to fetch manager records whose end time is not yet set:

```
Manager.objects.filter(end_time__isnull=True)
```

it return zero records.

However,

```
Manager.objects.all()[0].end_time==None
```

returns True in Django shell

The entries in the database are also stored as '0000-00-00'

How can i query to get Manager records whose end time is not yet set.?

Comment: It might be a better solution to use the [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html) setting to stop allowing `0000-00-00` in your database, and convert those values to `None`.

Comment: will this allow to fetch the records already in db?

Comment: If you convert `0000-00-00` to `null`, then `filter(end_time__isnull=True)` will return those rows.